# Creating a Database with html

Tags: image

I am trying to create a Database of all my albums. I have figured out a few things, but I am a novice html writer and I am confused about how to orientate some of my items.

I want to create rows of albums with the album title centered under each picture. Unfortunately; each time I add a album title, the image drops to the next "row"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gm1D.jpg)

What I would like to do is move "Get Your Wings (1974)" to the right of "Aerosmith (1973)" and another to the right of that ... and so on across the width of the page.

& Yes ... the album covers are clickable. When clicked, Explorer opens the folder containing the mp3s.

I'm not sure where to post my html code, so I uploaded it here:

http://rg.to/file/4171a1d9d442aa84b472bf9356c48c76/TEST_06.txt.html

Any assistance would be appreciated.

PS: Please be patient, I am just learning.
Thank You !

Comment: You should look into HTML positioning (being floats or flexbox). There are many great resources out there that show you, with examples, how things work. MDN is probably the best, CSS Tricks is very good, just to mention a few. You can even look into W3Schools. Of course, don't forget YouTube.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have, in fact, looked at many resources about this, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: can't edit comments more than 5 mins ????

Comment: I have tried to use "floats" but it didn't work. I also tried to make a table, but that didn't give the effect I want. Can anyone help ???

Comment: Post a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Sorry .. I have no idea what a "fiddle" is.<br> I posted my code in my first message. Rapidgator is easy to download from - just click the "Slow Speed Download" button.

Comment: I don't understand why this is so difficult. It seems this should be a simple thing to figure out. Can anyone else please help ???